# Hibernate ManyToMany relationship with independent parent

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 entites

**1) Nominee**
For Nominee management I have separate UI and operation, also this Nominee is used in other modules as well like Loan, etc So It does not have any mapping relation in it.

**2) Insurance,** which has code like this

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "INSURANCE_NOMINEE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "INSURANCE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NOMINEE_ID") })
public Set<Nominee> getNomineeList() {
    return nomineeList;
}

public void setNomineeList(Set<Nominee> nomineeList) {
    this.nomineeList = nomineeList;
}
```

I have Save Insurance code like this

```
Insurance insurance = buildInsuranceDomain(insuranceForm);
getHibernateTemplate().merge(insurance);
```

This works fine, as it inserts record into Insurance and Insurance_Nominee table.

But when I tries to delete this insurance record, it is going to delete record from Nominee table as well, but that should not happen, as that Nominee is used in other module as well like Loan, etc.

Delete code looks like below

> getHibernateTemplate().delete(insurance);

So how to specify that relation in Insurance domain entity ?

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I would expect that removing an Insurance instance would delete that record and any links in the join table but would be very surprised if the Nominee table was touched at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `Insurance`:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "INSURANCE_NOMINEE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "INSURANCE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NOMINEE_ID") })
```

and for `Nominee`:

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "INSURANCE_NOMINEE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NOMINEE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "INSURANCE_ID") })
public Set<Insurance> getInsuranceList() {
    return insuranceList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JoinTable(name = "INSURANCE_NOMINEE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "INSURANCE_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NOMINEE_ID")})
```

you are defining cascade option so this will save the child record automatically.Same case occurs for deletion too as on deleting it will call cascade delete which will remove related records when a parent record is removed.

You cannot expect a child which doesn't have Parent.

Comment: as per my understanding of your question you have to persist child value but it is not possible.on deletion of parent, child will be deleted.anyhow if you want to persist that value then remove the linking of both tables.no parent no child.